# How can I show multiple cells in the one textbox of the userform in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am now trying to fill the textbox in the UserForm(txtboxTransactionHistory) by the multiple cells data EXCEL when I click the button(CommandButton1_Click)

I have tried to copy the row until the employed cell, then hoped to paste to the UserForm TextBox directory.

I am not sure why does it show TURE instead of Row I copied, moreover how can I implemented that I want to see?

Environment: Excel for 2016 & Excel for Mac

The photo1 is the data of the sheet(TransactionHistory)

The photo2 is what I want to implement like

The photo3 is how it works right now

[image: photo1]
[image: photo2]
[image: photo3]

```html
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Set ws = Sheets("TransactionHistory")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Test")
i = 2
Do While ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
ws.Rows(i).Copy
   
    i = i + 1
Loop
Me.txtboxTransactionHistory = Rows(i).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)
 
End Sub
```

↓Class Module

```html
 Public CryptCurrency As String
 Public ExchangeRate As Double
 Public Quantity As Double
 Public TransactionDate As Date
 Public transactionType As transactionType
 
 Public Function tostring() As String
 tostring = CryptCurrency & " " & transcriptionType & " " & "quantity: " & Quantity & "rate: " & ExchangeRate
 End Function
```

====For later viewers====

Here is the Setting of TextBox to make a new line, for instance

```html
With TextBox1
        .MultiLine = True       
        .EnterKeyBehavior = True  
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long, j As Long, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, Info As String
Set ws = Sheets("TransactionHistory")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Test")
i = 2
Do While ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

    With ws
        'Info = Format(.Range("A" & i), "dd.mm.yyyy") & " " & .Range("B" & i) & " " & .Range("C" & i) & " Quantity: " & .Range("D" & i) & " Rate: " & .Range("E" & i)
        'Info = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range("A" & i, "E" & i).Value)), " ") 'Use this line if you just want the exact cells as they look in the sheet
        Info = tostring(.Range("A" & i), .Range("B" & i), .Range("C" & i), .Range("D" & i), .Range("E" & i))
    End With

    Me.txtboxTransactionHistory.Text = Me.txtboxTransactionHistory.Text & Info & vbCr
    i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Depending on which way you go I added both options to it.

You need to also make sure your textbox has `MultiLine` set to `TRUE` in the properties of the textbox for it to work.

To update. I don't know if you labelled the variables for your module elsewhere. Otherwise it should be like:

```
Public Function tostring(TransactionDate As Date, TransactionType As String, CryptCurrency As String, Quantity As Double, ExchangeRate As Double) As String
 tostring = TransactionDate & " " & TransactionType & " " & CryptCurrency & " " & transcriptionType & " " & " quantity: " & Quantity & " rate: " & ExchangeRate
 End Function
```

Then you can utilize my updated code above, this includes changing the `vbNewLine` to `vbCr` to cater for Mac.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can only touch the Mac right now, the "& vbNewLine" does not work on Mac default? (I mean it cannot begin the new line). I also tried "& vbCrLf", but not able to begin the new line, so maybe this is the Mac default.

Moreover, is that possible to use a class module "tostring" method that is below the click action code? Because that is the hint of this exercise, however, seems like I tried a different way.

Comment: My apologies again, I guess I have done similar thing under the "Class Module" on my post. My question is how to call the Function "tostring" inside the click action?

Comment: It's just like any other function. You can see it in my answer. I used your function you made and edited it so it would actually work. Otherwise how are you using the variables you are defining in your function? Is there something I'm missing with what you're asking?

Comment: Well, I got "Sub or Function not defined", I need more time to undestand

Comment: Where have you put the function? It needs to be in a module.

Comment: Ok, sorry again, I have put it in the class module, not a normal module. Now it workes. Thank you very much.